# How to include weight requirements for shipping method

Tags: orders, shipping-methods, table-rates, flat

So for a certain shipping method in our store(called flat rate) we want to charge two different flat rates:  one for orders that weigh no more than 13 ounces, and another for orders between 14 ounces and 1 lb.  How do this in default shipping methods called flat rate in magento?  we're on 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the event `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` to add custom logic to your observer. e.g

In your config.xml:

```
<events>        
    <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                <observers>
                    <frontend_shipping_rates_sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                        <class>mymodule_shipping/observer</class>
                        <method>calculateShipping</method>
                    </frontend_shipping_rates_sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        </events>
```

and then in your observer get the current carries (your flat rate) and then add your custom logic:

```
public function calculateShipping(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    if (Mage::getDesign()->getArea() === Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND) {

            $quote              = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $store              = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
            $carriers           = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $store);

if ($quote->getWeight() <= 13) {
   // Do something
 } else {
    // Do something else.
 }
}
```

You'll need to check what options you have available in the `$quote` object as `$quote->getWieght()` won't exist but at least it give you a starting point.

Comment: so basically this requires custom magento coding right?

Comment: @dave correct. Otherwise you could look at using Webshopapps matrix rates  http://webshopapps.com/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

Comment: thanks a bunch for clarifying because magento table rates just isn't enough for custom based shipping...one day the business prices rates on weight of order, then on per item, then on per specific item/region etc...there is no consistent way/table to summarize/generalize shipping methods.  Thanks again.

Comment: no problems dave, you could look at coding it yourself and create your own shipping method where you have full control over all the shipping rules.